# How to export result of SQL Server Query directly into Sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-server-2008

I had to run and export a result of SQL Server 2008 query in to SQLite daily. Is there any possible way to automate this process?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a linked server for the SQLite database in SQL Server to the SQLite database.  The place to start with this is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine).

Then you can set up a job using SQL Server agent to copy the data.  You can also set up a job using cron or your favorite scheduler.